# Woocommerce ID Called Incorrectly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im using a plugin IWD for woocommerce, and this is a consistent error I'm receiving. Seeking help with how to fix this? Im very new to code, and have attempted to understand it. But it is beyond my level of knowledge.

> [Wed Jul 29 19:36:02.765466 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 31401] [client
> 101.161.102.84:53742] id was called incorrectly. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace:
> require('wp-blog-header.php'),
> require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
> do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
> WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
> do_action('wc_ajax_iwd_opc_update_order_review'), WP_Hook->do_action,
> WP_Hook->apply_filters, IWD_OPC_AJAX::iwd_opc_update_order_review,
> woocommerce_order_review, wc_get_template,
> include('/plugins/iwd-woocommerce-checkout-suite/public/templates/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php'),
> WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
> added in version 3.0., referer: https://

Answer (score 1):

In WC 3.0 there was update adding getters/setters methods ( hello OOP ) for most public variables, but leave them public due to backward compability. In future it become private/protected I guess without additional permissions check and it'll become fatal error, not a warn.
So if before we have

```
$product = wc_get_product($id); // Instance of WC_Product
echo $product->id; // wrong
echo $product->get_id(); // nice
```

Due to your logs, you are using wd-woocommerce-checkout-suite plugin, last update was more than year ago, so your options

1. Update `iwd-woocommerce-checkout-suite/public/templates/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php` , line 30, from `$_product->id` to `$_product->get_id()`
2. Choose another plugin

Comment: If I edit to this code, it throws a fatal error - could you help?

`<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail( $_product->get_id() ) ): ?>
       
                                <div class="iwd-opc-review-products__item-img">
         <?php
         $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
         echo $thumbnail;
         ?>
                                </div>
       <?php endif; ?>`

Comment: Checked docs - it should be WC_Product. But if it throws error - try to replace `$_product->get_id()` with `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key )` @BrendanFredrich